# C# Помогите выделить из строки значение для фильтрации через Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, linq

я задаю выражение для Linq.Dynamic (динамически строкой указываю фильтрацию для Where)

Например я использую

```
var where = "Id > 2 && EventTrain == \"Transit\"";
var filtred= trains.Where(where).ToList(); //trains - список поездов
```

Помимо простых выражений возникла необходимость фильтровать по времени относительно текущего времени +- дельта.

Т.е. я придумал вот такое выражение

```
var where = "ArrivalTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100) && ArrivalTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinute(100)";
```

Но оно, естественно, не принимается Linq.Dynamic,
чтобы работать со временем нужно использовать DateTime в формате

```
  $"DateTime({now.Year}, {now.Month}, {now.Day}, {now.Hour}, {now.Minute}, {now.Second})"
```

Т.е. мне нужно из выражения

```
var where = "ArrivalTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100) && ArrivalTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinute(100)";
```

выделить DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100) и заменить это на реально вычисленное выражение по формату даты указанному выше.
выделить DateTime.Now.AddMinute(100) и заменить это на реально вычисленное выражение по формату даты указанному выше.

Я плохо знаком с регулярными выражениями, я попытался выделить минуты между скобками в выражении "DateTime.Now.AddMinute(DeltaTime)"

```
              if (Regex.Match(where, "DateTime.Now.AddMinute\\((.*)\\)").Success)
                {
                    var val= Regex.Match(where, "DateTime.Now.AddMinute\\((.*)\\)").Groups[1].Value;
                    if (int.TryParse(val, out var min))
                    {
                        var date = now.AddMinutes(min);
                        where = where.Replace("DateTime.Now", $"DateTime({date.Year}, {date.Month}, {date.Day}, {date.Hour}, {date.Minute}, 0)");
                    }
                }
```

Но такая простая регулярка работает только на примере

```
var where = "ArrivalTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100)"
```

а если несколько таких выражений да еще и могут быть скобки, например так:

```
 var where = "(ArrivalTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100)) && (ArrivalTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinute(100)) && (EventTrain == \"Transit\")";
```

Помогите заменить выражение DateTime.Now.AddMinute(DeltaTime) на вычисленное!

Comment: Строка фильтра формируется пользователем, если можно задать строку от пользователя и потом динамически ее выполнить. Если мне от пользователя прилетит строка "ArrivalTime > {DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(100)}" , то как мне ее выполнить?

Comment: Выражение `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-100)` должно работать. Обратите внимание на последнюю букву.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `Regex.Replace` и `Match evaluator`:

```
var where = "ArrivalTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100) && ArrivalTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinute(100)";
var pattern = @"DateTime\.Now\.AddMinute\(([^()]*)\)";
var now = DateTime.Now;
var res = Regex.Replace(where, pattern, x => 
    {
        var val= x.Groups[1].Value;
        int min;
        if (int.TryParse(val, out min))
        {
            var date = now.AddMinutes(min);
            return $"DateTime({date.Year}, {date.Month}, {date.Day}, {date.Hour}, {date.Minute}, 0)";
        } else return x.Value;
});
Console.WriteLine(res); 
// => ArrivalTime > DateTime(2018, 10, 17, 14, 35, 0) && ArrivalTime < DateTime(2018, 10, 17, 17, 55, 0)
```

[Демо на C#](https://ideone.com/fFtwUB)

**Описание регулярного выражения**

- `DateTime\.Now\.AddMinute\(` - строка `DateTime.Now.AddMinute(`
- `([^()]*)` - Захватывающая группа №1 (доступ к значению которой возможен через `x.Groups[1].Value`): 0 и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)` (`[^()]` — это отрицающий (негативный) символьный класс (т.к. начинается с `[^`), который находит все символы кроме указанных в этом классе: всё кроме `(` и `)`, а `*` — это квантификатор, благодаря ему находятся 0 и более символов, которые находит квантифицируемый шаблон)
- `\)` - символ `)`

Comment: Отлично! Те замена по патерну, заменитель вычисляется лямбдой. А не могли бы вы подробнее расписать сам pattern, что за что там отвечает?

Comment: @Aldmi Обновил, посмотрите. Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте. Я решил отказаться от числового шаблона в группе №1, но если хотите, можно заменить `[^()]*` на `-?\d*\.?\d+`, если там могут быть всякие числа.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: а можно подробнее про [^()]*

Comment: @Aldmi Я добавил краткое описание.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, зря вы пытаетесь делать это таким образом.

Задайте условие следующей строкой:

```
var where = "ArrivalTime > @0 && ArrivalTime < @1";
```

И далее используйте параметры в вызове метода:

```
trains.Where(where, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-100), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(100))
```

Ручная возня с регулярками не нужна.

Comment: Все бы хорошо но фильтр пользователь задает

Comment: @Aldmi - Пользователь вводит фильтр в `TextBox`? И знает синтаксис C#? Все эти `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes`? Или всё же у вас реализован нормальный выбор фильтров с использованием выпадающих списков, крыжиков и т. п.?

Comment: Пользователь это инженер, и он задает правило фильтрации используя параметр в JSON "Where" : "строка для фильтра"   "OrderBy" : "св-во для сортировки", достаточно указать в документации класс предметной области в моем случае train.cs чтобы инженер понял как ему сделать фильтр (Имена св-в и их типы).

Comment: @Aldmi - Гм. Может тогда написать простенькую документацию, где объяснить пользователю, как задавать фильтр с параметрами (`@0`, `@1`) и отдельным списком задавать сами параметры (id, время и т. п.). Имхо, это будет проще и работать надежней.

Comment: Думаю для инженера будет менее понятно задание многих параметров, да и булевую группировку условий никто не отменял, кто знает в каком выражении фильтрации встретится дельта времени))

Comment: Мне бы найти первое вхождение подстроки DateTime.Now.AddMinute(-100), выделить мин  между скобками, вычислить выражение и заменить первоначальное, повторить цикл